# How to get image path in twig using SonataMediaBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataMediaBundle to keep track of my images. I can render the image in twig using Sonata's helper:

```
{% media user.profilepic, 'reference' %}
```

This will render into an `<img src="the src">`

But, what I want to obtain is the naked path, so I can for instance, add a class to my img. Something like:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset(user.profilepic) }}">
```

Obviously,  `asset(user.profilepic)` does not return the path, but the object, and that object doesn't seem to contain the image's path.

**EDIT**

Found part of my answer, as well:

```
{% set foo %}
     {% path image, 'small' %}
{% endset %}
<img src="{{ asset(foo) }}" alt=""/>
```

Apparently the output of a block can be set to a variable, then pass that to the asset function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/reference/helpers.html) for helpers

There are several options. Media helper supports specifying the class

```
{% media media, 'small' with {'class': 'myclass'} %}
```

Also you can render just a path with "path" helper:

```
{% path media, 'small' %}
```

Comment: But how do I put that path inside an img's src? Or how do I pass it to the asset() function?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc did you try the first option? It will render into img with specified class. If this option doesn't fit to your expections, you can try
<img src="{% path media, 'small' %}" class="yourClass" />

Comment: Wow, it was that simple? Can't believe it. Please add it to the answer, too.

Comment: One more question, is it possible to do something like asset({% path media, 'small' %}) ? Because I'm getting a relative path and I need to pass it to the asset function.

Answer (score 0):

Since media-bundle 3.x those are:

Render the thumbnail:

```
{{ sonata_thumbnail(media, 'small') }}

{{ sonata_thumbnail(media, 'small', {'class': 'myclass'}) }}
```

Render the media:

```
{{ sonata_media(media, 'small') }}

{{ sonata_media(media, 'small', {'class': 'myclass'}) }}
```

Render the path:

```
{{ sonata_path(media, 'small') }}
```

Render the path to a sonata.media.provider.file context:

```
{{ sonata_path(media, 'reference') }}
```

Docs: https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataMediaBundle/en/3.x/reference/helpers/